# Configuring Burp Suite to intercept data between web browser and proxy server

Tags: authentication, proxy, suite, burp

I need to configure Burp Suite to intercept data between web browser and proxy server. The proxy server requires a basic authentication (Username & Password) while connecting for the first time in each session. I have tried the 'Redirect to host' option in Burp Suite(Entered the proxy server address and port in the fields):

**Proxy >> Options >> Proxy Listeners >> Request Handling**

But I can't see an option to use the authentication that is required while connecting to this proxy server.

While accessing google.com, **the request headers are:**

---

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) KHTML/4.13.3 (like Gecko) Konqueror/4.13
Accept: text/html, text/*;q=0.9, image/jpeg;q=0.9, image/png;q=0.9, image/*;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, x-gzip, x-deflate
Accept-Charset: utf-8,*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: close
```

**And the response is:**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: squid/3.3.8
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2016 15:14:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3163
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_URL 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
X-Cache: MISS from proxy.abc.in
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from proxy.abc.in:3343
Via: 1.1 proxy.abc.in (squid/3.3.8)
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were on the right track, just at the wrong place. You need to setup an upstream proxy at:

**Options>>Connections>>Upstream proxy**

There you can also setup the authentication

**Options>>Connections>>Platform authentication**

Here you can create different auth configurations, which will be done if the server requests it.